# Can draws from a Bayesian model be used in a Kolmorogov Smirnov test to assess group differences, even though we use the data for estimation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Suppose we have a Bayesian model where:

\begin{equation}
X_{iz} \sim N(\mu_z, \sigma^2_z) \\
\mu_z \sim N(0, 1) \\
\sigma^2_1 \sim Gamma(1,1) \\
\sigma^2_2 \sim Gamma(3,1) \\
\forall \ z \in \{1,2\} \ \ , i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}
\end{equation}

Suppose we obtained posterior estimates of all the parameters, and then sampled new values of $X_z$ by drawing sets of $\mu_z,\sigma^2_1,\sigma^2_2$, and then plugging them into the normal distribution. Then, suppose this results in $100$ draws for the new values of of $X_1$ and $X_2$, each ($X_1$ length 100, $X_2$ length 100).

Can I then plug the two vectors of the newly generated values into a Kolmogorov Smirnov Test, by doing something like the following?

```
ks.test(X_1, X_2)
```

I understand the K-S test relies on the two curves being independent, and generally if you obtain the parameters for a distribution from the data, and then compare the data, this is **invalid**. However, it does seem by drawing new values, there is independence based on the bayesian structure.

Is this test valid?